# My date of birth has been corrected in my new passport. Would this cause issues for future visa applications?

Tags: visas, uk, passport-renewals, nigerian-citizens

There's an error in my date of birth in my passport, which I may finally be able to correct after 6 years. I had tried to correct it when the passport was up for renewal last year, but I met a brick wall, so it was renewed under the same error. I have visited a couple of countries during this period, the last of which is the UK a few months ago. I've finally been given audience at the immigration service and I'd much rather correct the error. The thing is I'd like to renew my UK visa next year but I'm not sure how this change will be seen.

Would it attract a 10 year ban?

Comment: It's a Nigerian passport by the way.

Comment: It’s a genuine error and when you apply with the correct don next time provide the explanation and documentary proof.

Comment: When you last applied for a UK entrance clearance (visa), what date of birth did you put on the application? If your dates of birth have changed, then either that application or your new application was made with information that you knew to be factually incorrect.

Comment: I had a mistake in my birth date in my passport, I visited the UK in 1998 with a student visa, left the UK in 1998 as well. Fixed the error in 2000 or 2001, back to the UK in 2005 with no problems whatssoever, but as a crewmember.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but what do I do now? I dont want want to ruin my chances when applying for another uk visa. Could it affect my visa applications to other countries as well? I've waited so long to correct this  error and now I finally get the chance....

Comment: I have this same issue. Did you get it resolved? Did you have an issue reapplying? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Apply for your new visa, and attach commentary on your circumstances (along with a copy of any supporting documentation).  I would think that since you're voluntarily disclosing the information, you should have no problem.

This assumes that there is no information available that matches your name and correct birthdate, that would have precluded you from getting a visa previously.  Chances are, if your birthdate was just a few days or months out (as opposed to many years), they would already have figured that out, if it were the case.